# Best approach to transform and normalize claims from external authentication providers

Tags: asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I have multiple external authentication providers configured, e.g. Facebook, MSA and so on. When the user has signed in through any of these I want to transform/normalize the claims and maybe add additional custom ones, e.g. roles, before the user is sent back to the client. This way my client doesn't have to care about which provider the user signed in through since all claims will be the same in the token. I.e. no need to transform the claims in the client.

I also want to do this based on which provider the user signed in with.

I've looked into using `UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<TUser>` (which supports DI) and then register my implementation with `AddClaimsPrincipalFactory`. Is this the preferred method? However I can't see which provider was used to sign in here since authentication method is always `Identity.Application`. Nothing in the claims here suggests either which provider was used.

I've also looked into replacing `SignInManager<TUser>` and then override the method `SignInAsync`, but if I change the claims here it's not reflected in the token sent to the client. Also the parameter `authenticationMethod` is null the first time a user signs in and has gone through the consent and email/username confirmation screen.

I also would like to stay away from replacing most of the code that's handled automatically in the `GetExternalLoginInfoAsync` and `ExternalLoginSignInAsync` methods that's called from the account controller.

I would assume that transforming claims from external providers would be a first-class citizen feature, but it's not so clear how and where to do it, so it's stored correctly in DB (given that ASP.NET Core Identity is used) and the token.

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Comment: @MichelTol unfortunately not. I put this on hold, but now I've started to investigate again how to do this. Have you gotten any further?

Answer (score 1):

I've found that transforming the claims using the `IClaimsTransformation` works for me.It seems to be available in all versions of .NET Core and the info I add/update is passed on to the client calling IdentityServer.

Note that this class may be called multiple times, so the transformation should be idempotent.

Here is a sample claims transformation that will replace `given_name` with `DEMO`

```
public class DemoClaimsTransformator : IClaimsTransformation
{
    public Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
    {
        if (!(principal.Identity is ClaimsIdentity identity))
        {
            return Task.FromResult(principal);
        }

        var existingClaim = identity.FindFirst("given_name");
        if (existingClaim != null)
        {
            identity.RemoveClaim(existingClaim);
        }

        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("given_name", "DEMO"));

        return Task.FromResult(principal);
    }
}
```

I found out about it in this blogpost:
https://davidwalschots.com/how-to-add-additional-claims-to-the-httpcontext-user/

Comment: If I remember correctly `IClaimsTransformation` will transform incoming claims, not outgoing from IdentityServer.